# Google App Engine - Definition of backend

Tags: android, google-app-engine, client, backend

I recently started using Google App Engine, and I want to make a Android client for the server. I searched this topic, and I found multiple tutorials on how to make a "backend." Is this the same thing as a client?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "backend" is typically the App Engine server. It is what sends your GCM notifications, hosts your API calls, etc.

The "client" is typically the Android application that interacts with the App Engine server.

Comment: In that case, do you know a place where I could learn to make a client?

Comment: Have you read the [Cloud Endpoints Support documentation](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/cloud_endpoints)? There are samples and walkthroughs there. Otherwise, googling returns blog posts with samples such as [this one](http://devthots.blogspot.com/2012/07/building-awesome-android-apps-with.html).

Comment: I found the google developer tutorial on how to make a client. I misread the directions. It said that it makes an app FOR a backend. I read it as it makes an app backend. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think they have 3 definitions of backend.  The more general, informal use of the term would be the server that your Android client talks to (as described in accepted answer).

But GAE also supports 'backends, which are a special type of GAE instances:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview

And now they have introduced 'mobile backends' which seem to be pre-packaged GAE configurations for use with Android clients.  Those are specifically not GAE backends.